# What happens to the stored procedure data if the calling code disappears

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

If my Vb.net or c# web application calls a stored procedure that returns data to the web page  but in the middle of the stored procedure process the browser is closed.

What happens to the data that the stored procedure returned because the code that called it is no longer there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a Vb.Net or C# web application, that the code is not "inside" in the browser. **The browser is just the client side.**

**The server side runs the code**.

**The SP will finish**, even if you had any transaction in it, and no errors in the SP itself it will be commited.

The request was already sent from the client to the server, so it will be processed.

To see it, I would recommend you to use IIS and Attach to Process otption of Visual Studio.
Whit this you can see what is happening if you close your client side.

Answer (score 1):

That depends...

Are you checking [HttpResponse.IsClientConnected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.isclientconnected.aspx)  in your server code to periodically check if the client connection is still there? (This is useful when you are streaming large amounts of data to the client). But that won't help if it's simply a non-chunked/paged data fetch stored procedure call.

If not, the server side code will simply run to completion.

Answer (score 1):

Data will return but there is no one to received.

The end result will be if there is DML queries in your sp.